# Усложнённое разделение строки

Tags: python, парсер

Есть строка примерно такого вида -

```
str = 'a, b, c, d, "e, f, g"'
```

Суть в том, что нужно split эту строку по запятой, но не сплитить элементы внутри двойных кавычек.

Пример того, что нужно получить:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', "e, f, g"]
```

вот код, что есть, но он не сохраняет порядка, потому использование нецелесообразно [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Каков должен быть результат в случае `a, b, "c\", d", e"`?

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, код в картинке как текст :)

Comment: @gil9red Код иллюстративный и неправильный, так что не вижу особого смысла в этом.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно попробовать [обработать строку](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/f6f6948270feeb757b629468c8f32780610b720f/tokenize_string__using_tokenize.py#L13) через [tokenize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html).

Пример:

```
import io
import tokenize as T
from operator import itemgetter


def tokenize_string(data):
    tokens = T.tokenize(io.BytesIO(data.strip().encode()).readline)
    next(tokens)  # skip encoding token
    return list(filter(None, map(itemgetter(1), tokens)))  # filter ENDMARKER


text = 'a, b, c, d, "e, f, g"'

tokens = [x for x in tokenize_string(text) if x != ',']
print(tokens)
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '"e, f, g"']
```

**UPD.**

Принудительное удаление кавычек из строки:

```
tokens = [x[1:-1] if x.startswith('"') and x.endswith('"') else x for x in tokenize_string(text) if x != ',']
print(tokens)
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e, f, g']
```

Comment: у вас в ответе не такой список, который просил автор вопроса - кавычки в кавычках

Comment: @EugeneDennis, спасибо, вы правы, не заметил :)

Answer (score 2):

Могу предложить такой "топорный" метод

```
string = 'a, b, c, d, "e, f, g", 1, 2, 3, "5, 9, 0"'
index=0
max_index=len(string)
result=[]
while index < max_index:
    if string[0]==' ':
        string=string[1:]
    elif string[index]==',':
        result.append(string[:index])
        string=string[index+1:]
        max_index=len(string)
        index=0
    elif string[index]=='"':
        result.append(string[index:string[index+1:].find('"')+3])
        string=string[string[index+1:].find('"')+4:]
        max_index=len(string)
        index=0
    else:
        index+=1

print(result)
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '"e, f, g",', '1', '2', '3', '"5, 9, 0"']
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно заменить составные элементы на одинарные (чтобы привести к общему случаю), затем провести необходимую манипуляцию - `split`, и потом вернуть на место из словаря составную часть

```
import re
t = 'a, b, c, d, "e, g, h", k'
# находим с помощью регулярных выражений составные элементы
x = re.findall('"[^\"]*"', t)
# объявляем словарик
d = dict()
# пробегаемся по списку наших составных элементов ['"e, g, h"']
# в n - у нас индекс элемента, в xx - сам элемент
for n, xx in enumerate(x):
    # придумываем псевдоним для составного элемента на основе индекса
    q = '@{}'.format(n)
    # добавляем в словарь выходное значение составного элемента
    d[q] = xx.replace('"', '')
    # заменяем составной элемент на псевдоним
    t = t.replace(xx, q)
# здесь 2 цикла, в первом текст t, который стал выглядеть вот так:
# 'a, b, c, d, @0, k' подвергаем split(','), а затем к каждому элементу
# применяем strip (s.strip())
# во втором цикле пробегаемся по всем элементам и если элемент (g) является 
# ключом словаря (g in d) то заменяем его значением из словаря
tt = [d[g] if g in d else g for g in [s.strip() for s in t.split(',')]]
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e, g, h', 'k']
```

Comment: Можете прокоментировать код, пожалуйста? Или переименовать переменные. Стараюсь понять логику, спотыкаясь об однобуквенные нэйминги

Comment: добавил комменты

Comment: В случае двух таких элементов (с двойными кавычками) всё ломается

Comment: немного регулярку подправил

Comment: Всё таки не слишком, он сьедает элементы, даже если внутри кавычек нет запятых, просто находит две кавычки и заменяет их на f'@{n}'. Можете подправить, чтобы оно сплитило только если в кавычках есть запятая?

из строки 'OU001;;"asd ""ds, asd""";asd; asd. 134\n'
получается 'OU001;;@0@1@2;asd; asd. 134\n'
А должно остаться такой же

Comment: составной элемент может быть простым - в этом случае он просто лишиться кавычек

Answer (score 0):

Моё решение. Работает с любым количеством вложенных в двойные кавычки элементов и любым количеством элементов с двойными кавычками.

```
def _recursive_filter(line, result=None):
    try:
        if not result:
            result = []
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith('"'):
            temp = ''
            i = 0
            while line[i+1] != '"':
                temp += line[i]
                i += 1
            else:
                temp += f'{line[i]}"'
                result.append(temp)
                line = line[len(temp):].strip(', ')
                _recursive_filter(line, result)
        else:
            temp = ''
            i = 0
            while line[i] != ',':
                temp += line[i]
                i += 1
            else:
                temp += ','
                result.append(temp)
                line = line[len(temp):]
                _recursive_filter(line, result)
        return [x.strip(', "') for x in result]
    except IndexError:
        if temp:
            result.append(temp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(_recursive_filter('"d, e, f", g, h,'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def split_line(line, sep):
    mas = line.split(str(sep))
    kow = 0
    new_mas = []
    for i in mas:
        if '"' in i and kow == 0:
            kow = mas.index(i)
        elif '"' in i and kow != 0:
            new_mas.append(','.join(mas[kow:mas.index(i) + 1]).split('"')[1])
            kow = 0
        elif kow != 0:
            pass
        else:
            new_mas.append(i)
    return new_mas
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]